# How to stop visual studio from auto expanding code regions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

As the title describes, how I could stop visual studio from auto-expand code region? I'm using visual studio on a C++ project.

For example, sometimes when I delete some part of my code it unfolds a lot of regions far away up from where the line was deleted.

This behavior also happens sometimes when I'm scrolling, from nothing it expands the region.

I saw there's an option on edit > outlining > stop outlining

[image]

But this disables all kind of code folding, I just want to stop visual studio herself from auto-expanding any kind of code.

This is frustrating, it happens a lot of times and I need to stop what I'm doing to fold everything again.

Comment: I reported it without any success https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/727742/spurious-region-expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

It seems that my original approach suggested below does not always work. I'm not sure why. So that makes it even less helpful of a workaround. But it does seem to work a lot of the time.

Original Response:

I also have this problem in VS and hence I found your question. I have not specifically noticed the auto-expand as it relates to scrolling.

However, I did discover a workaround that may be better than nothing in some cases. If it auto-expands on you in response to a cut or paste action, you can hit ctrl+z a bunch of times to restore the regions it auto-expanded to their previously collapsed state.

The reason why I say a bunch of times is because it appears as though VS records the auto-expansion of each region it chooses to expand as an un-doable action.

So, if you hit undo enough times it will restore the various regions to their previous state before you did the cut or paste action.

Of course, hitting undo a bunch of times will get you to the point where it un-does your original cut or paste that you were trying to do too. But re-doing that will probably be faster than manually restoring the collapsed state of the regions it auto-expanded on you.

I can reliably reproduce the bug you described (at least it is reliably reproducible in my project). Just paste a bunch of comment lines, for example. Then start cutting them one by one (ctrl+x). Eventually, the auto-expand will happen.